# Finding min/max/saddle $z=x^2-y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**

> Consider $z=x^2-y^2$.

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2x \Rightarrow 2x=0 \Rightarrow x=0$

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-2y\Rightarrow -2y=0 \Rightarrow y=0$

$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=2>0$

$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}=-2<0$

Can I stop here and say that $(0,0,0)$ is a saddle point?

Comment: Yes, because the determinant of the Hessian matrix will be $2(-2)-\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\right)^2<0$

Comment: @Wore: In other words, there is another partial derivative and a determinant to calculate, so he cannot just "stop here."

Comment: @RoryDaulton what I was saying is that there is no need to calculate the next derivative, because if $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ have different signs, the determinant will definitely be different from zero and negative (notice that the mixed derivative is squared, so the quantity after the minus will always be less than or equal to zero).

Comment: @Wore: Oh, I see, you are correct. Thanks for your further explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.

Writing $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$ we have $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x} = 0 $ and as you have found $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}= 2$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}= -2$, then

1) The Hessian matrix at $(0,0)$ is given by $$Hf(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 2> 0$ and $\lambda_2 = -2 < 0$, then  it is a saddle point.

2) You could also notice that for any disk centered at $0$ the function $f$ assume values greater or less than $0 = f(0,0)$, then it wouldn't be neither a maximum nor a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

no you must form Hessian and say Hessian is not positive or negative definite hence it's a saddle point.
$H = \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\\
        \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\\
        \end{pmatrix}$
$$det(H)<0$$ so eigenvalues are not co-sign.

Answer (score 1):

Adding that the mixed second order derivatives vanish, you have found that the function is stationary at the origin with Hessian $\DeclareMathOperator{diag}{diag}H=\diag(2,-2)$. As $e_1^t H e_1 = 2 > 0$ and $e_2^t H e_2 = -2 < 0$ $H$ is indefinite, and you found a saddle point there.

[image: The scene]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you will have to calculate the Hessian matrix $H=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2} &\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y} &\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\end{bmatrix}$ and determine if $H$ evaluated in the critical point is positive definite, negative definite, or neither of those (in which case you will say that the critical point is a saddle point).

However, if $z=f(x,y)$ is a function of class $C^2$ (the second order derivatives exists and are continuous) then you will have that $$\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial y\partial x}$$ and $$\det(H)=\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}-\left(\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}\right)^2$$

Therefore, when you have a function that is $C^2$ (like $z=x^2-y^2$, or like most of the functions in a course of multivariate calculus) we can conclude the following:

If you already know that $\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2},\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}$ have different signs, then the product $\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}$ is negative and $\det(H)$ will be negative **independently of the value of** $\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}$. Thus, the Hessian matrix $H$ will be neither positive nor negative definite.

So, to conclude, my answer would be that you can stop there and conclude that your point is a saddle point, but only if you really understand why.